# How to add methods in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an ObservableCollection that generates a button with the data of a Model in which I pass an image, a color and a link. The problem is that I want to put a method in it and when I press the button, call the method that I put into the ObservableCollection.

[Edited]

I am making a FloatingButton like this:

This floating button is made with a custom control. Each small button has a background color, an image and a link which are in Items.cs. In the viewmodel, I create an ObservableCollections with the Items.cs data that every time I add a list, a new button is added. What I want to do is to be able to add in addition to an image, a link and a color, a method that depending on the button you press, does what I want.

If I press the first small button that will be the first index in the list, that when I press it, it does one thing, and if I press the fourth button it will call another method that I want.

Example:

```
ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://google.es/", Image = "web.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Method = "DoSomething" });

ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://facebook.com/", Image = "facebook.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Method = "OpenFacebookApp" });

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            //Do Something
        }
        public void OpenFacebookApp()
        {
            //Open Facebook App
        }
```

This is my code:

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //==============================================================
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    //==============================================================



    string imageprimarybutton;
    public string FirstImage
    {
        get => imageprimarybutton; set
        {
            imageprimarybutton = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //=============

    string firstButtonColor;
    public string FirstButtonColor
    {
        get => firstButtonColor; set
        {
            firstButtonColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //=============

    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get => isVisible;
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //=============

    public ICommand LaunchWeb { get; private set; }
    public ICommand OpenFloating { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemList { get; set; }

    //=============

    public ViewModel()
    {
        IsVisible = false;
        FirstImage = "dots.png";
        FirstButtonColor = "#B52D50";

        OpenFloating = new Command(openFloatingButton);
        LaunchWeb = new Command(async (url) =>
        {

            string AppLink = (string)url;

            await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(AppLink);

        });


        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Items>();

        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://facebook.com/", Image = "facebook.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" /*What I want: Method=OpenApp*/});
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://twitter.com/", Image = "twitter.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://www.instagram.com/", Image = "insta.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://google.com/", Image = "web.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
       


    }

    /* And here the method I call in ItemList
     
    public void OpenApp() {
    
    Do something

    }


     */

    bool firstStart = true;
    bool nextClick = true;

    public void openFloatingButton()
    {
        

        if (firstStart)
        {
            FirstImage = "cross.png";
            FirstButtonColor = "#6F1B31";


            IsVisible = true;
            firstStart = false;

        }
        else
        {
            if (nextClick)
            {
                FirstImage = "dots.png";
                FirstButtonColor = "#B52D50";

                IsVisible = false;
                nextClick = false;
            }
            else
            {
                FirstImage = "cross.png";
                FirstButtonColor = "#6F1B31";

                IsVisible = true;
                nextClick = true;

            }



        }
    }

}
```

Items.cs:

```
  public class Items : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string url, image, color;

    public string Website
    {
        get { return url; }
        set {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("url");
        }
    }
    public string Image
    {
        get {
            return image;
        }

        set{
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("image");
        }
    }

    public string ColorButton{
        get {
            return color;
        }

        set{
            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("color");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: each item has a completely unique method?  Or does each item call the same method with a different argument?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a delegate (e.g. [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1)) property to `Item`?

Comment: I want each item has a unique method

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know how to use delegates @JHBonarius

Comment: it would really help if you gave us a better description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Check my updated post.

Comment: add a `Command` to your `Items` class

Comment: I guess each "small button" are bound to an Items object, you should handle the click event in the button and retrieve the bindingcontext (Items) and implement any logic for opening a link.

Comment: 'and don't work' - again you're not telling us what happened and what code you implemented. He has given you something to work with and you've haven't even shown us what you have implemented. Give us a better description than 'don't work' if you expect an answer.

Comment: In Items class, I added the command that @Jason said  " public ICommand Method { get; set;}".   In ViewModel class, I added in the list, the method that I create in Items like this:  "ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "facebook.com/", Image = "facebook.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Method=new Command(OpenFloating););". The method OpenFloating should open and close the floating button. but when I click the button who have this item with the link of facebook and the method of OpenFloating, it don´t do nothing.  I don´t know how to implement this.

Comment: did you bind the Button's command property to the VM command?

Comment: The button is in a CollectionView and binded with ItemsSource.

Comment: MainPage.xaml:   ` <local:FloatingButton
       
        ItemSource="{Binding ItemList}"
        CollectionViewVisible = "{Binding IsVisible}"
        PrimaryImageSource="{Binding FirstImage}"
        PrimaryButtonColor="{Binding FirstButtonColor}"           
        />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple example for you and hope you can understand how the binding works.

First I add a `Name` property in the Items model which is use for distinguish different button:

```
public class Items : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string url { get; set; }
    string image { get; set; }
    string color { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }

    public string Website
    {
        get { return url; }
        set
        {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Website");
        }
    }
    public string Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }

        set
        {
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    public string ColorButton
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }

        set
        {
            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ColorButton");
        }
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in the View Model, there is a `MethodCommand` which you can bind to the buttons:

```
public class viewModel {

    public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemList { get; set; }

    public ICommand MethodCommand { get; set; }

    public viewModel()
    {

        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Items>();

        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://facebook.com/", Image = "facebook.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Name = "facebook"/*What I want: Method=OpenApp*/});
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://twitter.com/", Image = "twitter.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Name = "twitter" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://www.instagram.com/", Image = "insta.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Name = "insta" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://google.com/", Image = "web.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50", Name = "web" });

        MethodCommand = new Command(test);
    }

    private void test(object obj)
    {
        string itemName= obj as string;

        Console.WriteLine(itemName);

        if (itemName == "facebook")
        {
            //perform your method with facebook
        }
        else if (itemName == "twitter")
        {
            //perform your method with twitter
        }
        else if (itemName == "insta")
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code in Xaml, bind the `MethodCommand` to the `Command` and bind `Name` to the `CommandParameter`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="myPage"
             x:Class="App416.MainPage">

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    

                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference myPage}, Path=BindingContext.MethodCommand}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"
                            />
             
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

And at last, set the bindingContext in MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new viewModel();
    }

}
```

Please feel free to ask me any question if you have:).